# CMake Error in Netbeans (double-check your ROS_PACKAGE_PATH)

Tags: cmake, rospack, rosbuild

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've installed Netbeans 7.1.1 as sudoer in Ubuntu 11.10. Just as it is described in the Wiki at http://www.ros.org/wiki/IDEs#Installing_NetBeans.

However, everytime I try to build my own package which is a identical copy of the tutorial from http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/WritingPublisherSubscriber%28c%2B%2B%29, I get the output:

```
mkdir -p bin
cd build && cmake -Wdev -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=`rospack find rosbuild`/rostoolchain.cmake  ..
[rosbuild] Building package hha
CMake Error at /opt/ros/electric/ros/core/rosbuild/private.cmake:110 (message):
  [rosbuild] rospack found package "hha" at "", but the current directory is
  "/home/<***>/workspace/ros/hha".  You should double-check your
  ROS_PACKAGE_PATH to ensure that packages are found in the correct
  precedence order.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/electric/ros/core/rosbuild/public.cmake:180 (_rosbuild_check_package_location)
  CMakeLists.txt:12 (rosbuild_init)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
make: *** [all] Fehler 1


BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 157ms)
```

What is going on? If I execute 'make' in a terminal, everything works fine! :-/

Also, I get the following correctly identified path of 'rospack find hha'

```
/home/<***>/workspace/ros/hha
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29186/cmake-error-in-netbeans-(double-check-your-ros_package_path)/) by [Florian](https://answers.ros.org/users/1922/florian/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2012-03-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem is due to the changes made to Netbeans configuration files' location from 6.x to 7.x. Please add `source /opt/ros/electric/setup.bash` to `netbeans.conf` based on the information given here:

http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqNetbeansConf

and here:

http://wiki.netbeans.org/FaqWhatIsUserdir

---

Originally posted by [Mani](https://answers.ros.org/users/1858/mani/) with karma: 1704 on 2012-09-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0